# REST: The field 'EventDate' of type 'DateTime' cannot be used in the query filter expression

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

This is my REST Service URL to call SharePoint 2013 list.

```
http://site/_api/lists/getbytitle('EventCalendar')/items?$filter=EventDate gt '2016-05-01T05:52:12Z'
```

When I try to run this URL am getting an error:

> The field 'EventDate' of type 'DateTime' cannot be used in the query
>   filter expression.

But instead of `EventDate` if I change some other field it works fine. Why it's not working for the `EventDate` field?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
datetime'yourDate'
```

So your request looks like

```
http://site/_api/lists/getbytitle('EventCalendar')/items?$filter=EventDate gt datetime'2016-05-01T05:52:12Z'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this also bit me in the past. You can read about the background [in this blog post](http://neganov.blogspot.com/2013/06/filtering-items-by-date-range-using.html).

The solution i used was to change from the OData based query to a CAML query. The endpoint used for this is `http://site/_api/lists/getbytitle('EventCalendar')/getitems` and you have to change your REST method from GET to POST.

There are quite some references for that online, e.g. [this CodeProject article](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1181172/SharePoint-REST-API-CAML-Query).